# A non-deleted answer to a deleted question?

Tags: bug, deleted-questions

Something weird is going on with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53230681/7296893).

It's an answer on a question that got an answer on SO, then got migrated to MSO, rejected, and then deleted. However, it seems the answer hasn't been deleted, I can still vote and comment on it, and it's displayed as a non-deleted answer.

[image]

Comment: Yet it's not accessible by < 10k users.

Comment: It's been deleted now.

Comment: the red arrows are the best.

Comment: First try to realize the truth...there is no circle tool. Then you will see it is not the circle that squiggles,  only yourself.

Answer (score 11):

Sometimes occurrences like this occur due to bugs in the system.

However, there's [a script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34725/buried-but-not-dead) that goes around and deletes any non-deleted answers to deleted questions, to take care of such inconsistencies.